# Grafana mysql query

Tags: mysql, grafana

Please suggest the MySQL queries for grafana.
I have data with I required MTTR from data, I'm getting expected output with add "15" as an integer in the query but not with count queries.

```
from "[with integer][1]" image. 
sum(seconds_to_resolve) / 15 /60  as "MTTR"  ---> value is 25.4
```

Getting different value if mentioned

```
from "[with count Function][2]" image.
sum(seconds_to_resolve) / count(seconds_to_resolve) / 60 as "MTTR" ---> value is 322
```

query:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(created_on,$__interval),
  sum(seconds_to_first_ack) AS "seconds_to_first_ack",
  sum(seconds_to_resolve) AS "seconds_to_first_resolve",
  count(seconds_to_resolve) AS "COUNT",
  sum(seconds_to_resolve) / count(seconds_to_resolve) /60  as "MTTR"
FROM alerts_report
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(created_on) AND
  service_name = 'RKSOL'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY $__timeGroup(created_on,$__interval)
```

[with integer]    [image: 1]

[with count Function]    [image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

I would use `average` function to calculate MTTR (*mean* time to resolution):

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(created_on,$__interval),
  sum(seconds_to_first_ack) AS "seconds_to_first_ack",
  sum(seconds_to_resolve) AS "seconds_to_first_resolve",
  count(seconds_to_resolve) AS "COUNT",
  avg(seconds_to_resolve) AS "MTTR"
FROM alerts_report
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(created_on) AND
  service_name = 'RKSOL'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY $__timeGroup(created_on,$__interval)
```

Comment: `sum(seconds_to_resolve) / count(seconds_to_resolve) /60` getting diffrent value. 
another value from `sum(seconds_to_resolve) / 15 /60  as "MTTR"`. 

when i add "count(seconds_to_resolve)" to query, receiving higher value.

Comment: im expecting output like 
`sum(seconds_to_resolve) / count(seconds_to_resolve) /60` should be same like `sum(seconds_to_resolve) / 15 /60  as "MTTR"` 
Please sugggest